# Dynamic import without using global namespace?

Tags: webpack, dynamic-import

Lazy loading, with proper dependency resolution, without globals.

Say I have three modules, `main`, `lazy`, and `dep`. Both `main` and `lazy` import `dep`. `main` may or may not need to load `lazy` at some point in time. How can I configure webpack to:

1. bundle `main` and `dep` together (ok this is easy)
2. bundle `lazy` by itself, without `dep`. When it loads it resolves`dep` from the `main` bundle.
3. without writing anything in the window or global namespace

I can find how to do (2) or (3) but not both at the same time.

When I use `SplitChunksPlugin` I get (2) without (3) - the output writes `window.webpackJsonP` into the global namespace. For my purpose this is bad for two reasons. I have to support DOMLess environments with no `window` object, and my project is a library/widget that runs on other peoples websites/apps, so I can't be leaving globals lying around.

When I configure it as two entrypoints, I get (3) without (2) - my `lazy` file includes the `dep` module code, which seems redundant.

```
// index.js / entrypoint
import Main from "./Main.js";
new Main().sayHi().doStuff();

// Main.js
import Dep from "./Dep.js";

export default class Main extends Dep {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "Main";
  }

  doStuff() {
    import("./Lazy.js")
      .then(module => {
        let lazy = new module.default();
        lazy.sayHi();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(`owch: ${err.message}`);
      });
    }
}

// Lazy.js
import Dep from "./Dep.js";

export default class Lazy extends Dep {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "Lazy";
  }
}

// Dep.js
export default class Dep {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Dep";
  }

  sayHi() {
    console.log(`hello, my name is ${this.name}`);
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware that `webpack` pollutes global namespace...